# How can I transfer AutoCorrect entries from one computer's MS Word 2013 to another's?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have tried copying whole directories listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926927) from the source computer to the destination computer, but this has not made the AutoCorrect entries show up on the destination computer.

The following are the directories copied from source and placed in the exact location on the destination computer:

- C:\Documents and Settings\Raj\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates
- C:\Documents and Settings\Raj\Application Data\Microsoft\Office
- C:\Documents and Settings\Raj\Application Data\Microsoft\UProof
- C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
- C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office
- C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof

Still, I am not getting the AutoCorrect entries on the destination computer's MS Word 2013. What can I do to get the AutoCorrect entries to transfer?

Comment: Have you tried copying individual files? There may be something your overwriting that forces Word to start from scratch?

Comment: @codingCat, actually, I did it individually first, and then tried the entire directories when the individual transfers didn't work.

Comment: Then I would definitely suggest the utility I listed below. Good luck.  :-)

Comment: If that utility does not work, try [Kutools for Microsoft Word](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-word.html) ($39, free 45 days trial with full features).

Comment: Not sure what to do with this question as multiple people have responded with very nice answers. It turns out that although the AutoCorrect entries DID transfer, the options did not, and some of my options depending on Math AutoCorrect being used outside of math regions (which had to be re-selected in the destination computer's MS Word's Proofing options). Once I enabled it, all AutoCorrect functioned as it did on my source computer's MS Word installation.

Answer (score 3):

First, what you are doing should work in theory. The process of moving the autocorrect has not changed in recent versions of office. The following article is the most straight forward description that I have found. It details the 2010 version of Office, but should still work with the 2013 version as well.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956104.aspx

You stated that you copied the entire folders. Have you tried the single files? You may be forcing a reset of word by overwriting something unexpected.

If neither of those ideas work I can suggest this utility:

http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#Moving_AutoCorrect

I haven't had a reason to try it myself (so use with care), but it comes highly recommend.

I hope this helps.  :-)

Comment: Also have a look at [How to move AutoCorrect entries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926927).  As you correctly state, the process hasn't changed and while written for Word 2007, these instructions are still correct.  I've successfully used them myself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some VBA that will export the autocorrect entries to a file and then import then from that file. Run the export on the first computer, transfer the code and exported file to the second computer, and run the import. One limitation, though: this method won't transfer any rich text entries. Things like `:-)` becoming ☺ or `<=>` becoming ⇔ when you're trying to export it. If someone knows how to tweak the code so it *does* work, I'd be grateful.

Be sure to change the constant file path to something that works for you.

```
Const strDelimeter As String = "|||"
Const fPath As String = "C:\Temp\AutoCorrectEntries"

Sub ExportAutoCorrect()
    Dim ace As AutoCorrectEntry
    Open fPath For Output As #1
    For Each ace In Application.AutoCorrect.Entries
        If Not ace.RichText Then
            Write #1, ace.Name & strDelimeter & ace.Value
        End If
    Next
    Close #1
End Sub

Sub ImportAutoCorrect()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fLine As String
    Dim aceName As String
    Dim aceValue As String
    Open fPath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, fLine
        If Left(fLine, 1) = """" Then fLine = Mid(fLine, 2)
        If Right(fLine, 1) = """" Then fLine = Left(fLine, Len(fLine) - 1)
        i = InStr(1, fLine, strDelimeter)
        If i > 0 Then
            aceName = Left(fLine, i - 1)
            aceValue = Mid(fLine, i + Len(strDelimeter))
            Application.AutoCorrect.Entries.Add aceName, aceValue
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Manually Move AutoCorrect Entries`

This method is typically used for formatted AutoCorrect entries.
It will move the default Template file from one computer to another computer.
Location for all autocorrect lists:   [user]/appdata/roaming/microsoft/office/*.acl
On Computer 1:    (This is the computer that you want to copy the Auto-Correct List FROM.)

1. Make sure to Close ALL Microsoft Office programs.  (Outlook, Word, Excel, etc…)
2. Copy the `Normal.dotm` file to an intermediate location* that the destination computer, Computer 2, can access the file.

`Normal.dotm` location is: `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates`

On Computer 2:   (This is the computer that you want to move the Auto-Correct List TO.)

1. Browse to the Templates folder:

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates
2. Rename the `Normal.dotm` file to `Normal.bak`to back it up.

Right-click on Normal.dotm & click Rename.
Type Normal.bak & press ENTER.
3. Make sure to Close ALL Microsoft Office programs.  (Outlook, Word, Excel, etc...)

4. Copy the Normal.dotm file (AutoCorrect entries) from the intermediate location*.   (Ex. USB drive, on-line or on a shared network.)

The Electronic File Storage: LSU Overview article will help if you are unsure how to do this.
5. Paste the `Normal.dotm`file in the following folder: `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates`
[Click Here](https://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=17078)